# Where to load the data for an Adapter ? In Activity ? or in Adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

For a List view you must have an adapter. To fill the list items you need data. Now here is the question:

1. is this a good idea to download the data in custom adapter ?
2. or better is download data in activity & pass it to adapter ?
3. or their is any better way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a better answer for this question:

- prepare your data in *Activity*, then send it in your *Adapter*. It may be downloading the data via `AsyncTask` or from `SQLite` or something else.
- In your *Adapter* load the data via `AsyncTask` or from `SQLite` or something else.

But the better option is loading the data in Activity & use it in Adapter. It will help you to make your codes cleaner & it will give you more flexibility, to manage your data. But in some situations, you may consider to prepare the data in Adapter; if you have difficulties to load it in Activity.

Both works fine, Its up to you which will you consider.

Answer (score 4):

looks it is only one question with three option

```
is this a good idea to download the data in custom adapter or better is download data in activity & pass it to adapter  their is any better way to achieve that ?
```

Create `AsyncTask from Activity` and `set the data to adapter from onPostExecution` callback function

a good tutorial [link1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

2- [Load ListView in background AsyncTask](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html)

Comment: yes.. that's the way I used. But sometimes, in some cases if I need to download the data from Adapter; then is this acceptable ?? is this a  good approach ??

Comment: not very good option but fissible .... basically even can't say bad approach  depends on condition as I think in some condition it looks good option if implemented in a structured way but in general we prefer in activity

Answer (score 0):

You can download in any activity class, then send the data through the Broadcast, edit your adapter and finally update the adapter i.e list by calling :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```